# Why can't object (.obj) files be moved across platforms?

Tags: c++, c

Why can't we move .obj files from c compilation across OS platforms and use it to build the executable file at the end?

If we can do so can we call C a platform independent language like Java?

Comment: C++ and C are platform independent in  the sense that you can compile the same source code everywhere. The compiled binaries are not platform independent (unlike Java with its JVM).

Comment: Java is platform independent because of JVM, C is native code, java is managed code (in the microsoft terminology).

Comment: Java code is not platform independent, as it only runs on one platform - the JVM. The difference is just that someone else has already compiled the JVM for the target platform. If you get someone to compile your portable C code for the other platform, it will run there too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *C language* **is** platform independent.

The files generated by the compiler, the object and executable files, are platform dependent. This is due to the fact the ultimate goal of a compiler is to generate an executable file for **the target architecture only**, not for every known architecture.

Java *class* files are platform independent because Sun was the only designer of Java, it actually made all the rules (from bytecode to file format and VM behavior) and everyone else had to adapt.

This didn't happen with native binary formats, every OS made its format, compiler made its object format and every CPU has its own ISA.

Comment: So why is .obj file not deleted after getting the executable file. why is it left behind even after getting the executable files?

Comment: @sive Because compiling cost resources and time. Java compilation is relatively easy, C++ is not. Keeping temporary file speed up the build process **a lot**. You could get confident with Make in order to understand why object file are not deleted.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely nothing in any specification that says this CAN'T be the case. (Note that the languages C and C++ are both platform independent, but the OBJECT files produced by C and C++ are what is NOT platform independent)

However, because C and C++ are both languages designed for performance, most compilers produce machine code for the target system. And you may then say "but my Linux machine runs on the same processor as my Windows machine", but of course, that's not the ONLY difference between object files or executable files on different OS architectures. And whilst it may be possible to convert object files containing machine code for the same processor from one format to another, it's fraught with problematic things like "what do with inlined system calls" (in other words, someone called `gettimeofday` via the `std::chrono` interface, and the compiler inlined this call, which is a call directly to the OS - well, Windows has no idea what `gettimeofday` is, it's called `GetSystemTime` or some such, and the method of calling the OS is completely different...)

If you want an OS independent system, then all object files must be "pure" - and of course, both systems need to support the same object file format (or support conversion of them).

One could make a C or C++ compiler that does what Java (and C#, etc) does, where the compiler doesn't produce machine-code for the target system, but produces a "intermediate form" - but that would be a little contrary to the ideas of C and C++, which is that the language is designed to be VERY efficient, and not have a lot of overhead. If portability is more important than performance, maybe you want to use Java? Or some other portable language...

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms use different object file formats (ELF for Linux, COFF/PE for Windows), so an object file built on one platform may not be usable on another.

Remember that an object file is (usually) native machine code, just not in an executable form.

Answer (score 0):

C is cross-platform in source code level.

Once it is compiled, the binary is subject to many factors.

In architecture level, it is possible to generate intermediate object code like LLVM, and do JIT on target machine so that the code fits for target architecture.

However, unless you are doing free-standing development, the platform dependency can comes to play a party preventing you to directly run the code. These dependency may include linking parameters, difference in implementation of standard libraries, platform-specific features, etc.

There is still exception, if the OS provide binary-level compatibility (like BSD ), you may indeed run code compiled for other platform directly.